# false Transaction mined but execution failed, and eth was deducted from my metamaskwalltet

Tags: remix

I was trying to deploy my smart contract to  Ethereum Mainnet network using Remix IDE,although it compiles successfully but when I try to deploy it I get this error message

"false Transaction mined but the execution failed"

My transactions hash is

0xc70e27fabd6a79441b6c70304e35e256be8024607637700e191b9654584faa57

Answer (score -1):

The error on etherscan is quite explicit:

```
 Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]
```

So you need to provide a bit more gas.

Comment: how to do it, my money was deducted, if now I will run the program for creation of token what will happen to money deducted